# WebGl 2 is not defined in Google Chrome despite hardware acceleration enabled

Tags: google-chrome, gpu, hardware-acceleration, webgl2

I'm trying to use WebGL 2 on a website but I can seem to get it to work on my PC. Says it's not available. I can't figure out if it's the graphics driver or OpenGL's version, but here's some info. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Here is my hardware.

**Chrome version: `Version 108.0.5359.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)`**

`lsb_release -a` outputs:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Linux Lite 5.6
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

`lspci | grep VGA` outputs:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
```

`glxinfo | grep 'version'` outputs:

```
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
    Max core profile version: 0.0
    Max compat profile version: 2.1
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 2.0
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 21.0.3
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 2.0 Mesa 21.0.3
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0.16
```

And here are the settings for chrome.

`chrome://gpu/`:

[image: graphics features]
[image: problems detected]

`chrome://flags/`:

[image: flags]

`chrome://settings/system`:

[image: hw acceleration]

Report from [WebGL Report](https://webglreport.com/?v=2)

[image]

Comment: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series indicates that you are using a GPU from 2008. It's not unlikely that it simply doesn't support WebGL2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found in your printout fragment `Max GLES[23] profile version: 2.0`, which is confirmed by this [tech sheet](https://h-node.org/videocards/view/en/106/Intel-Corporation-Mobile-4-Series-Chipset-Integrated-Graphics-Controller--rev-07-). So your maximum supported Open GLES version is 2.0 which equals to WebGL (version 1). You would need a graphics controller which supports Open GLES 3.0 as that corresponds to WebGL2.

So, in short -- everything's fine with Chrome, but your hardware resp. its driver doesn't support Open GLES 3 and therefore not WebGL2.